# Copy template-page at end of new document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a word document containing a single page that I'd like to use as a template to create another word document. The new document will contain multiple pages with replaced content from the template page.

```
**Document 1**
Page 1 (Template Page)

**Document 2**
Page 1 (Copy of Template Page)
Page 2 (Copy of Template Page)
Page 3 ...
```

The template for now only contains the line "Test #" and I'd like to replace the "#" with the current page number. My current code is as follows and should generate a new document containing two pages.

```
        string filename = @"C:\xxxxx_in.docx";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc2 = oWord.Documents.Add();

        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc1 = oWord.Documents.Open(filename);
            object matchCase = false;
            object matchWholeWord = true;
            object matchWildCards = false;
            object matchSoundsLike = false;
            object matchAllWordForms = false;
            object forward = true;
            object format = false;
            object matchKashida = false;
            object matchDiacritics = false;
            object matchAlefHamza = false;
            object matchControl = false;
            object read_only = false;
            object visible = true;
            object replace = 2;
            object wrap = 1;
            object findText = "#";
            object replaceWithText = i.ToString();

            oDoc1.Content.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range oRange = oDoc1.Content;
            oRange.Copy();

            oDoc2.Range(oDoc2.Content.End - 1, oDoc2.Content.End - 1).Paste();
            oDoc1.Close();
        }


        object outputFileName = @"C:\xxxxx_out.docx";
        oDoc2.SaveAs(ref outputFileName);
        oWord.Quit();
```

The problem is, that I'm getting an exception for the line ...

```
        oDoc2.Range(oDoc2.Content.End - 1, oDoc2.Content.End - 1).Paste();
```

> System.Runtime.InteropService.COMException: "The object invoked has
>   disconnected from its clients."

How can I fix this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by opening the second document in a seperate word application. Here is the working code.

```
        string filename = @"C:\xxxxx_in.docx";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord1 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord2 = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        int pages = 3;

        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc2 = oWord2.Documents.Add();

            for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc1 = oWord1.Documents.Open(filename);
                object matchCase = false;
                object matchWholeWord = true;
                object matchWildCards = false;
                object matchSoundsLike = false;
                object matchAllWordForms = false;
                object forward = true;
                object format = false;
                object matchKashida = false;
                object matchDiacritics = false;
                object matchAlefHamza = false;
                object matchControl = false;
                object read_only = false;
                object visible = true;
                object replace = 2;
                object wrap = 1;
                object findText = "#";
                object replaceWithText = i.ToString();

                oDoc1.Content.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                    ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
                    ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range oRange = oDoc1.Content;
                oRange.Copy();

                oDoc2.Range(oDoc2.Content.End - 1, oDoc2.Content.End - 1).Paste();

                if (i + 1 < pages)
                {
                    oDoc2.Range(oDoc2.Content.End - 1, oDoc2.Content.End - 1).InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);
                }

                oDoc1.Close(false);
            }

            object outputFileName = @"C:\xxxxx_out.docx";
            oDoc2.SaveAs(ref outputFileName);
            oDoc2.Close(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Do something.
        }
        finally
        {
            oWord1.Quit(false);
            oWord2.Quit(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code in the question is that `oDoc1` is being instantiated for every pass through the loop.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc1 = oWord.Documents.Open(filename);
```

Put this *before* the `for` loop so that the document is opened only once. Then `oDoc1` should not become disconnected.

**Better** would be to use `Documents.Add` for creating the new document (`oDoc1`) from the "template". This way there's no danger of the template file being  changed. Then, in order to repeat the "empty" page (the content as it is before the values have been replaced) try using the `Range.InsertFile` method to bring in the content of the "template" at the end of `oDoc1`.